# Windows Media Player DRM (WMDRM)

Tags: sdk, drm, windows-media-player

I found a picture online: https://beta.techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/q6uvf.jpg

and had an idea: I wanted to play around with DRM on .wmv and .wma files

I don't want to decrypt DRM content or strip DRM out of a file (because I don't have any files with that)

I want to encrypt a file create a license server, and then decrypt that using Windows Media Player (like that picture describes but with my own files and server)

I read on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_DRM

that I need Windows Media Rights Manager SDK to package content and create licenses

I found that some documentation on how to use that here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediasdkstuff/2008/09/26/wmrm-sdk-10-1-2-best-practice-sample-code/

but the page is disabled and IA doesn't have any snapshot of it

So does anyone have that SDK with some sample code (the language the sample code is in does not matter but C# would be nice)

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: Perhaps you should check the current DRM offering: [PlayReady DRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/playready-client-sdk)

Comment: would like the old one not the latest PlayReady if possible

Comment: Why would you not use the latest PlayReady? If the plan is to try and break it, you not likely going to find a lot of assistance. And note that these SDK's are not generally just downloadable, they require licensing them.

Comment: don't want to break it, its just for fun
I know they require a license, but if someone would be kind enough to share it (its old so...) that would be awsome